# Is there a more efficient way of converting tif files in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, gis

Here I convert tif files to a Stata dataset with `gdal`. For simplicity, I'll link the [ones](https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/worldclim/v2.1/base/wc2.1_10m_prec.zip) at the lowest resolution (if it matters, I'm using the 2.5m resolution files).

Here's my code:

```
### Be sure to copy the file I've
### linked to your current directory

from osgeo import gdal
import pandas as pd, os, glob

for file in glob.glob("*.tif"):
    ds = gdal.Open(file) # Make TIF into a dataset

    xyz = gdal.Translate(file+".xyz", ds) # Extracts coordinates
    
    xyz = None

    df = pd.read_csv(file+".xyz", sep = " ", header = None)
    df.columns = ["_CX","_CY", "tmin"]
    df.to_stata(file+".dta", write_index=False)
    
    del ds

    files_in_dir = glob.iglob('*.xyz')

    for _file in files_in_dir:
        print(_file)
        os.remove(_file)
        
    os.remove(file)
```

The code does all of what I need it to do- but at higher resolutions, it just takes an hour and a half or so, and I'm interested in optimizing it. Any way I might make this run even faster?

Comment: You could move this to a function and apply `multiprocessing` to fan out to multiple cores. I don't know what gdal does, so can't really say if its better. You'll need to be more judicious in deleting those .xyz files.

Comment: It's impossible to tell you why the code is slow without a proper explanation of *what the code is intended to accomplish*. You should try testing the performance of e.g. a single `gdal.Translate` call, and also try reading the `gdal` documentation for any performance hints or asking on any support forum / issue tracker etc. for `gdal` about the poor performance. Stack Overflow is not tech support.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The original post says that the only goal of this code is to make these gif files into Stata-data files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can spread it over multiple cores with the `multiprocessing` module. This doesn't always speed things up, and can actually make things worse if you end up over committing memory. But its worth a shot.

```
from osgeo import gdal
import pandas as pd, os, glob
import multiprocessing as mp

def gdal_izer(file):
    ds = gdal.Open(file) # Make TIF into a dataset

    xyz = gdal.Translate(file+".xyz", ds) # Extracts coordinates
    
    xyz = None

    df = pd.read_csv(file+".xyz", sep = " ", header = None)
    df.columns = ["_CX","_CY", "tmin"]
    df.to_stata(file+".dta", write_index=False)    
    del ds

    # TODO: Fix = this will delete xyz files used by other
    # processes. Should it just be deleting the one file?
    files_in_dir = glob.iglob('*.xyz')

    for _file in files_in_dir:
        print(_file)
        os.remove(_file)

    # TODO: removing the tif seems pretty extreme. maybe
    # save it in case something goes wrong?
    os.remove(file)

    
def main():
    # note: all cores is likely too much
    files = glob.glob("*.tif")
    with mp.Pool(min(len(files), mp.cpu_count() * .6)) as pool:
        result = mp.map(gdal_izer, glob.glob("*.tif"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```